# Warning: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe column with state abbreviations (AK, VT, etc).  I want to break them down into regions to replace the data in the column with numeric values.  I put each region in a list, like so:

`south <- c("KY", "TN", ...)`

and tried this code:

`df[df$state == south] <- 1`

But this is when I get the warning (longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length)

I am not sure why.  Is there a better way to replace state abbreviations so I can make them numeric factors?

Comment: `df[df$state %in% south] <- 1` ?

Comment: That looks like it worked.

Comment: When I try to make the column numeric, it gives me another error:                                  invalid 'length' argument                                                                                       `df$state <- as.numeric(df$state)`

Comment: You would need to give a [mcve]. I don't see how that line could trigger that error.

Comment: For your second error, you may use:  `df$state <- as.numeric(as.factor(df$state))`